# Language Support has an unwanted Chinese language option

Tags: language-support

When I open System Settings and open the Language Support dialog, there is an option in the list, for (I think) Chinese. As far as I can recall I have never installed this language myself.

[image: The Language Support dialog]

Searching for language-pack in Synaptic, the following packages are listed as installed: language-pack-en, language-pack-en-base, language-pack-gnome-en and language-pack-gnome-en-base. If I click the Installed Languages button in the Language Support dialog, I do not see Chinese listed as installed: only English has a checkmark.

Is this additional language taking up space? How can I remove it?

Here is the output of `locate language-pack`:

```
% locate language-pack
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-en
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-en-base
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-gnome-en
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-gnome-en-base
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-en/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-en/copyright
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-en-base/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-en-base/copyright
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-gnome-en/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-gnome-en/copyright
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-gnome-en-base/changelog.gz
/usr/share/doc/language-pack-gnome-en-base/copyright
/usr/share/locales/install-language-pack
/usr/share/locales/remove-language-pack
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-pack-en-base_1%3a11.10+20120103_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-pack-en-base_1%3a12.04+20111229_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-pack-en_1%3a11.10+20120103_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-pack-en_1%3a12.04+20120202_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-pack-gnome-en-base_1%3a11.10+20120103_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-pack-gnome-en-base_1%3a12.04+20111229_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-pack-gnome-en_1%3a11.10+20120103_all.deb
/var/cache/apt/archives/language-pack-gnome-en_1%3a12.04+20120202_all.deb
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-en-base.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-en-base.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-en-base.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-en-base.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-en.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-en.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-fr-base.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-fr-base.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-gnome-en-base.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-gnome-en-base.md5sums
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-gnome-en-base.postinst
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-gnome-en-base.postrm
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-gnome-en.list
/var/lib/dpkg/info/language-pack-gnome-en.md5sums
```

And here is the output of `ls /usr/share/locale-langpack`:

```
% ls /usr/share/locale-langpack 
en     en@boldquot  en_GB  en@quot  en_US
en_AU  en_CA        en_NZ  en@shaw  en_US@piglatin
```

Comment: Clearly, you don't have Chinese installed. Don't need to worry. :)

Comment: Weirdly, I _can_ choose that language and some elements will be translated, but indeed… I think this was happening on my netbook as well, so I'll see if I can find more information and file a bug report. Sounds like this is being decidedly abnormal, so kind of outside Ask Ubuntu's realm.
Thanks for your help, jokerdino! :)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/130649/39372

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem (Chinese showing up in lists and once even as the system language) and this command solved it:

```
sudo locale-gen --purge
```

Answer (score 1):

As an extra package, it does take up some space. You can remove it by clicking on the 'Install / Remove Languages...' button.

[image]

Here, note that I have Tamil installed as one of my supported languages. To remove it, click on the above-mentioned button.

[image]

Then, untick the check box next to the language. After that, click on 'Apply Changes' and you would have removed all your unwanted languages.

Comment: English is the only language listed as installed, that method has been tried...

Comment: Indeed, that's the bit that's really weird and crazy: as I mentioned, no other languages in that list are checked. Do you know if there is a specific list of installed languages somewhere that feeds the list in the first screen's Language tab? Perhaps that would shed some light on this.

Comment: @DylanMcCall Edit your question and add the output of `locate language-pack`

Comment: Okay, this magically went away in Ubuntu 12.04. You have been helpful, so I'll just give you the happy checkmark :)
(And I bet if someone gets here, your answer will probably be the answer they need anyway).

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by some conflicting configuration files. Following link may be useful. Look into post #3. 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2050993

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

As 1.st language you probably see the Chinese and below that is English.

Just click on English and drag it over the Chinese.

You can see now how the "symbols language" fades out.

Log out.